# (The lack of) ZED board sound card support in GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, drivers, audio, embedded

I am trying to convince a sound card to work on a custom HW similar to an Avnet ZED Board.

The original driver example was based on a heavily (a patch to vanilla is about 180k lines) modified 3.14.12 kernel and was called zed_adau1761. The "sound card" is not handled within one driver, it is divided into three logical parts:

1. Codec driver adau1761-i2c.c,
2. A driver taking care about streaming data axi-i2s.c,
3. A driver setting up the two above to work together, zed_adau1761.c.

Unlike the first two drivers, the third one was probably never mainlined, and existed only in one branch of now probably defunct part of Analog Devices Github fork of a kernel.

The development board is still sold according an Avnet web page, so there might be some hackers using it.

My problem is that today tools are not able to work with such an old kernel as was the one about 7 years ago, and at the same time the old kernel is full of other problems, but the old driver is not included with the newer kernels and neither works with newer kernels.

Is the 3. driver mainlined under a different name? Or am I trying the wrong way to make the soundcard work?

Thank to anybody with a better insight into the problem!

Comment: A quick internet search found this driver on an embedded kernel instance: https://github.com/mathworks/xilinx-linux/blob/master/sound/soc/adi/zed_adau1761.c . It's a 4.9 kernel which is better than what you have (*if* it's working of course). Anyway that's the common issue with embedded which often sticks to older kernels. When a driver (or platform) isn't upstreamed, you're stuck with an old kernel

Comment: Yes, it's the only copy available till now (the Analog github is kind of messed up and full of 404s), but it's just an exact copy of the old (and AFAIK the only) version of the machine driver I know. I wasn't successful in making it work with the rest of the kernel though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An attitude to SoC drivers has changed over the years in a way.

The support to OF (Open Firmware - in other words for configuration in device tree) has been reworked, improved and extended in the area of sound card drivers.

It's preferred to use a general solution instead of writing a number of machine drivers (the "glue" driver - 3. in my question). In this case it's a "simple-audio-card" machine driver and an appropriate configuration in device tree:

```
zed_sound {
        compatible = "simple-audio-card";
        simple-audio-card,format = "i2s";
        simple-audio-card,name = "ZED ADAU1761";
        simple-audio-card,dai-link@0 {
                format = "i2s";
                cpu {
                        sound-dai = <&axi_i2s_0>;
                };
                codec {
                        sound-dai = <&adau1761>;
                };
        };
};
```

This solution works with up to date kernel. Tested with long-term stable - 5.10.x at the time of the test.